# How to read CURL POST on remote server?

Tags: php, curl

This is my `cURL` `POST` function:

```
public function curlPost($url, $data)
{
    $fields = '';

    foreach($data as $key => $value) { 
      $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
    }

    rtrim($fields, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info   = curl_getinfo($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
}

$this->curlPost('remoteServer', array(data));
```

How do I read the `POST` on the remote server?

The remote server is using PHP... but what var in `$_POST[]` should I read

for e.g:- `$_POST['fields']` or `$_POST['result']`

Comment: Is the remote server running PHP? If so it's in `$_POST`. If it is running something else, use that language's framework for retrieving posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code works but i'll advice you to add 2 other things

A. `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` because of  HTTP 302

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
```

B. `return` in case you need to output the result

```
return $result ;
```

Example

```
function curlPost($url, $data) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

print(curlPost("http://yahoo.com", array()));
```

Another Example

```
    print(curlPost("http://your_SITE", array("greeting"=>"Hello World")));
```

To read your post you can use

```
 print($_REQUEST['greeting']);
```

or

```
 print($_POST['greeting']);
```

Comment: I did as you said but the $_POST['data'] is also empty

Comment: look at the example .. i was sending `greetings` not `data` .. you can not get `$_POST['data']`  if you want to get data use `array("data"=>"Hello World")`

Comment: You can check what you're working with, with: `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Yes but my $data in my code is an array originally. Also you removed the code I originally had for converting the array to a string and then sending it. Should I send the array as is the way you have sent it and then read each variable separately ?

Comment: I removed it because `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` can accept array directly  .. you don't need to convert it to string

Comment: Ok I will try it that way as well

Answer (score 0):

as a normal POST request ... all data posted can be found in $_POST ... except files of course :) add an `&action=request1` for example to URL

```
if ($_GET['action'] == 'request1') {

  print_r ($_POST);

}
```

EDIT: To see the POST vars use the folowing in your POST handler file

```
if ($_GET['action'] == 'request1') {
  ob_start();
  print_r($_POST);
  $contents = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  error_log($contents, 3, 'log.txt' );
}
```

Comment: The $_GET['action'] -> print POST is working but I cannot print the POST being it on a remote server and the script getting called from CURLPOST.... so it will be helpful if u can see my code and tell me which variable to read in POST exactly .. also I have already tried $_POST['fields'] && $_POST['result'] both are empty

Comment: sorry ... i'll show you how to see it . look at the EDIT part i've added to my Answer

Comment: I am getting permission issues to create the file. PHP Warning:  error_log(log.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\submit.php on line 9. Also Where will the file be created

Comment: you can add path ... depending on you server or localhost "/var/log/log.txt" for example ... if you have rights to create a file manually ... create 'log.txt' ... each request will just add data to this file

Comment: Oh it's a windows server so i changed the path to this error_log($contents, 3, 'C:\Users\vsheth\Downloads\log.txt'); But I still get the permission error in php log

Comment: you can try the other options too, instead of 3 ... check them here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php ... you can use email to

Comment: If you use IIS ... add the 2 permissions releted to IIS for the directory ... it is Microsoft issue

Comment: Many times had the same problems as you :) Hope I helped. You can access your data in `$_POST` by keys of `$data` array ... but it's good to know how to manage such kind of situations